# Banish the tab bar on Safari 8 (when tabs are open)

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

With a trackpad, one can do a pinch and see all open tabs. It's a very nice interface and really well done. The thing is, with this feature, there is really no need for the tab bar, and things would look a lot cleaner without it. Yet Apple doesn't seem to give us the ability to hide it when more than one tab is open.

Does anyone know any hacks to hide it?